# Make equal height depending on the column in front

Tags: javascript, html, css

can someone please help me I have this example here, I need the col that has the biggest text, the col infront of that to take the same height not all the other columns I tried something like this but it always takes the height for all.. :/ Can you help me please?

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
#matchline-dynamic {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border: solid 1px #b7b7b7;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
}.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
#matchline-static {
    background: white;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.wrapper2
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;

}

.boxi
{
 

  height: 100px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="col-xs-6  ">
                <ul id="matchline-ul" class="todo-list matchline-options ui-sortable">
                                                                                                                                                                                            <li id="matchline-static" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="width-100" id="match-lines-options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="1">
                            <div id="take-match-line-answer-text">
                                <span class="text padding-right-20">asdasd</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                <li id="matchline-static" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="width-100" id="match-lines-options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="0">
                            <div id="take-match-line-answer-text">
                                <span class="text padding-right-20">sdfsdf</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                <li id="matchline-static" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="width-100" id="match-lines-options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="3">
                            <div id="take-match-line-answer-text">
                                <span class="text padding-right-20">asd</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                <li id="matchline-static" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="width-100" id="match-lines-options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="2">
                            <div id="take-match-line-answer-text">
                                <span class="text padding-right-20">s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and s</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                      </ul> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 ">
                <ul class="todo-list ui-sortable">
                                                                            <li id="matchline-dynamic" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="handle width-100 ui-sortable-handle">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="3">
                              <div id="take-order-answer-text">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                            <div class="float-left">
                          
                                <span class="text padding-left-10">s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and s</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                <li id="matchline-dynamic" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="handle width-100 ui-sortable-handle">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="2">
                              <div id="take-order-answer-text">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                            <div class="float-left">
                          
                                <span class="text padding-left-10">sdf</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                        <li id="matchline-dynamic" class="boxi">
                        <span class="handle width-100 ui-sortable-handle">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="0">
                              <div id="take-order-answer-text">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                            <div class="float-left">
                          
                                <span class="text padding-left-10">sdf</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                <li id="matchline-dynamic" class=" boxi">
                        <span class="handle width-100 ui-sortable-handle">
                        <input type="hidden" name="1024[]" value="1">
                              <div id="take-order-answer-text">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                            <div class="float-left">
                          
                                <span class="text padding-left-10">lasdh ajhsdg kjahgsdkhafsdgasdchhj adjkajsd</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I thought It would work something with the child, but I am new in coding and dont know ..

Comment: The problem is that you are using duplicate IDs, which is invalid markup. Please use classes instead, and target them with `.matchline-dynamic` and `.matchline-static` respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme)